# could not set the submit button value dynamically angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set the submit button value dynamically using Angular.js but its not coming properly. I am explaining my code below.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <input type="submit" value="{{ !model ? 'reset' : model}}" />   

  </body>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.model = "Create new order";

});
```

Here I need when there is no value assign to the `$scope.model` then button name should reset.

Comment: Its button label name.

Comment: I updated my post. Please check it.

Comment: Your code works just fine. Can you observe your console for any errors? Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syrovhLc/).

Comment: I am getting `Error: Lexer Error: Unexpected next character at columns 16-16 [?] in expression [ model = !model ? model : 'reset'].` error in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<input type="submit" value="{{ model = !model ? model : 'reset'}}" />
```

### Snippet:

```js
    angular.module("a",[]).controller("ac",function($scope){
    $scope.querylist =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
    $scope.name = 'World';

    $scope.model = undefined;

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="a" ng-controller="ac">
     <input type="submit" value="{{ model = !model ? 'reset' : model}}" />   
    </div>
```

Comment: I did as per you but its throwing `Error: Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 16-16 [?] in expression [ model = !model ? model : 'reset'].` error.

Comment: Your main problem is `reset`. you have updated this in your question with `'reset'` So please try that. It should work well

Comment: Please provide a mark as answer. if it's working @subhra

Comment: @RameshRajendran ([marking is optional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)) His code works without any corrections, _he probably had the wrong syntax_. Your answer holds no value for others

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Did you run the snippet? Why I need to provide this? because he told him code does not working after that change. That's why am providing the snippet.